# Проблема с mouseout

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть скрипт открытия меню и закрытия нужно что бы через 10 секунд блок закрылся но только если мышка за пределами блока, а если мышка на блоке то что бы он не закрывался

пробовал так но не выходит:

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#closea").click();
    $("#closediv").fadeIn(); 
  });

$(function() {
  $("#closea").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("closea")) {
      $(this).removeClass("closea");
      $("#closeimg").attr("src", "../img/up.png"); 
   var k=0;
   $(".close").mouseover(function(){k=1;});
   if(k==1){
   setTimeout(function(){
   $("#closea").addClass("closea");
   $("#closeimg").attr("src", "../img/down.png"); 
   $("#closediv").slideToggle("slow");
  },5000);
   }else{
   k=0; 
   }
   
   
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("closea");
      $("#closeimg").attr("src", "../img/down.png");
    }
    $("#closediv").slideToggle("slow");
  });
  

  
});
```

```html
<div class='close'>


<div id='closediv'>
   контент в блоке
</div>
<a id='closea' onclick="close(this)" class="closea">
  <img id='closeimg' src="../img/up.png" style="width:30px">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: у вас в js в пятой строке лишнее `});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делается это по такому принципу

```js
$(function() {
  var timeout;
  $('.menu').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.options').css('display', 'block');
  });
  $('.menu').mouseover(function() {
    clearInterval(timeout);
  });
  $('.menu').mouseout(function() {
    var e = this;
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      $(e).find('.options').css('display', 'none');
    }, 10000);
  });
  $('.menu').each(function() {
    var e = this;
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      $(e).find('.options').css('display', 'none');
    }, 10000);
  });
});
```

```css
body {font-family: arial}
.menu {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu .select {
  display: block;
  width:200px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.menu .options {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 1px);
  width:200px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.menu .options .option:hover {
  background-color:black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu">
  <div class="select">Пункт 1</div>
  <div class="options" style="display:block;">
    <div class="option">Пункт 1</div>
    <div class="option">Пункт 2</div>
    <div class="option">Пункт 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: с моим примером не работает

Comment: у меня меню которое сразу открыто. нужно что бы после 10сек блок закрылся но ели мышка не наведена на блок если наведена, то закрывать не надо

Comment: @BedOmar, всё равно не понимаю, почему не подходит

Comment: потому что не работает в моем случае

Comment: скрипт закрытия начинает работать когда я забираю мышку с option а у мне нужно что бы скрипт активировался сразу когда загрузится страница

Comment: @BedOmar, изменил ответ. Смотрите

Comment: СПАСИБО! РАБОТАЕТ ВСЁ!